# Retrieve Dataset  with PetaPoco

Tags: c#, petapoco

My company has now started using PetaPoco as ORM tool to map to database.I have a stored procedure that returns a Dataset with a table.  Using the text template I have created a Poco for my stored procedure. Now when I get my data back I want  to perform some operation based on values in each row.
How

```
Database dbs = MainDatabase.Instance;         
            var summary = dbs.Fetch<ClassParticipantSummary>(Sql.Builder.Append(";EXEC enrol.ClassParticipantSummaryGet @SiteId = @0 , @ClassId = @1" ,SiteId ,ClassId));

       summary.Find(predicate<ClassParticipantSummary> (("WHERE name= @name", new { name = "petapoco" }));
```

I understand my above statement can be absolutely wrong. I am just trying to get it working.

Can someone tell me how to do a search in petapoco object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `Where` to the SP exec in the same way you can't do it in SQL. PetaPoco just executes SQL and map the results.

If you want to search inside the SP results, you can use plain `Linq`, because PetaPoco returns a `List`.

```
var FilteredList = (from rec in summary 
                    where rec.name == "petapoco" select rec).ToList();
```